# Mocking existing methods in Clojure

Tags: clojure, mocking, reify

I am trying to use `with-redefs` and `reify` to mock methods in clojure. I do not have a clue on where to get started with those. Can anyone please give me an example of mocking a method? The documentation on the internet is of no help for me as I am totally confused with it at this point of time.

Comment: are you looking to mock the methods of a class, or mock a clojure function (that was defined with def or defn)

Comment: @Arthur Ulfeldt : I am looking to mock both

Comment: You may find useful https://github.com/asyntactic/dynamic-reify and this basic example for functions and vars https://gist.github.com/jaimeagudo/8980813

Answer (score 3):

The book "The Joy of Clojure (Manning)" might be a good starting point, section '13.2  Testing' has some information with regards to (among others) the technique you mentioned - using the `with-redefs` macro.

Comment: This is for the 1st edition of the book. If you are using the 2nd Edition of "The Joy of Clojure", this has moved to section 17.2

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to spy/mock/stub a function `bar` and test how many times it got called in function `foo`. A simple example could be:

```clj
(defn bar [] ...)

(defn foo [] 
  (bar)
  (bar)
  (bar))

(deftest 
  (let [args (atom [])]
    (with-redefs [bar (fn [x] (swap! args conj x))] 
      (foo)
      (is (= (count @args) 3)))))
```

---

Well, I agree the code above is a bit tedious. 
You can try out the following macro:
(I put invoke history into meta data)

```clj
(defmacro with-mock [vr & body] 
  `(with-redefs [~vr (with-meta 
                       (fn [& ~'args] (swap! (-> ~vr meta :args) conj ~'args))
                       {:args (atom [])})] 
     (do ~@body)))
```

#### usage:

```clj
(with-mock bar 
  (foo)
  (is (= (-> bar meta :args deref count)
         3)))
```

With a little utilities functions, the macro above could become a powerful tool. 
The expressiveness of Clojure is so great.